# Object JavaScript, cannot read property of undefined... That was read just before

Tags: javascript, css, object

I try to make an object that move, resize and change the color of a div randomly every second.

In my classical HTML page there is

```
<div id="Rectangle1"></div>
```

Here is my code

```
var colors = ["red","yellow","blue","dark","green","pink","purple"];

function Rectangle(tag){

    this.moveNShape = function() {
        //Defining new values
        this.width = Math.floor(Math.random()*250)+50; 
        this.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*250)+50; 
        this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+100; 
        this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+100; 
        this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*7)];
        //Update the view
        this.tag.css("position","absolute").css("height",this.height).css("width",this.width).css("left",this.x).css("top",this.y);
        this.tag.css("backgroundColor",this.color);
        //Launch again
        setTimeout(this.moveNShape,1000);

    }

    this.tag = $('#'+tag);
    this.moveNShape();

}

var rect1 = new Rectangle("Rectangle1");
```

It works one time and after I get the error "Cannot read property 'css' of undefined". I tried to rewrite it in many ways but I can't find a solution.

Can you explain my mistake ?

Thank you =)

Comment: Which line are you receiving the error on? You have a couple calls to `.css`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**bind**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to set the `this` variable to the `Rectangle` object.

The reason you were getting that error before is when `moveNShape` was called via the `setTimeout`, `this` became `window` because the execution context had changed

```
    var colors = ["red","yellow","blue","dark","green","pink","purple"];

    function Rectangle(tag){

        this.moveNShape = function() {
            //Defining new values
            this.width = Math.floor(Math.random()*250)+50; 
            this.height = Math.floor(Math.random()*250)+50; 
            this.x = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+100; 
            this.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*400)+100; 
            this.color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*7)];
            //Update the view
            this.tag.css("position","absolute").css("height",this.height).css("width",this.width).css("left",this.x).css("top",this.y);
            this.tag.css("backgroundColor",this.color);
            //Launch again
            setTimeout(this.moveNShape.bind(this),1000);

        }

        this.tag = $('#'+tag);
        this.moveNShape();

    }

    var rect1 = new Rectangle("Rectangle1");
```